# React Native Text Input Auto-Fill Email issues

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, autofill

I am using the React Native Text Input but I am having an issue with the iOS autofill feature when I am using the field for an email entry to sign up a user. I get autofill recommendations for names, state, city and country. But not email, I am unsure as to why. Here is the example of our text field/text input components.

**Text Field Component**

```
<TextInput {...props} style={props.tall ? styles.tallTextInputStyle : styles.textInputStyle} adjustsFontSizeToFit />
```

**Form Input Component**

```
<TextField
    testID="emailInput"
    placeholder="name@example.com"
    error={errors.email || invalidEmail || duplicate}
    validated={validated.email && !error}
    keyboardType="email-address"
    selectTextOnFocus
    returnKeyType="done"
    autoCapitalize={false}
    onSubmitEditing={formSubmitted}
    onChangeText={(val) => updateEmail(val.trim())}
    autoCompleteType="email"
    textContentType="emailAddress"
/>
```

I have already added the Associated Domains to the Xcode project and this seemed to make no difference at all.

Any advice on the autofill issues I am going through would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and it is appeared to be a problem with **KeyboardAvoidingView** from 'react-native', so I changed it to **KeyboardAwareScrollView** from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view' and the problem was resolved